# How to get a formatted date and time string from `now`?

Tags: rebol, red

I'm using "Red Programming Language" version "0.6.4" on Windows and making a command line application.

I don't know much Red language and I don't understand many things. I did go over "work in progress" docs at (https://doc.red-lang.org/en/) before asking here.

I need to get a date and time string formatted as `yyyymmdd_hhmm`.

I've started with code like this:

```
Red []
dt: to string! now/year
print dt
```

which gives me `2019` but I need the other things month, day and time to obtain something like `20190608_2146`

I tried also:

```
Red []
dt: to string! now/precise
print dt
```

which gives me `8-Jun-2019/21:47:51.299-07:00` but again what I needed was `20190608_2147`

***Question:***
How to modify the code above to obtain something like `20190608_2147` from `now`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a script for Rebol and Red called 'Form Date' that will format dates/times in a similar fashion to STRFTIME. The Red version is [here](https://github.com/rgchris/Scripts/blob/master/red/form-date.red).

```
do %form-date.red
probe form-date now "%Y%m%d_%H%M"

print first spec-of :form-date
```

Within the script are individual snippets of code used for formatting the various components of a date! value.

You don't need the script for your specific example though, you can extract and join the various components thus:

```
date: now
rejoin [ ; reduce-join
    form date/year
    pad/left/with date/month 2 #"0"
    pad/left/with date/day 2 #"0"
    "_"
    pad/left/with date/hour 2 #"0"
    pad/left/with date/minute 2 #"0"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As the above solution has some problems under Rebol2 here a variation that works with Rebol and Red the same way

```
date: now
rejoin [ 
    date/year
    next form 100 + date/month
    next form 100 + date/day 
    "_"
    next form 100 + date/time/hour
    next form 100 + date/time/minute 
]
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is another way:

```
rejoin [
    now/year 
    either 10 > x: (now/month) [join "0" x][x]
    either 10 > x: (now/day) [join "0" x][x]
    "_" 
    either 10 > x: first (now/time) [join "0" x][x]
    either 10 > x: second (now/time) [join "0" x][x]
]
```

Red has `pad`, so rgchris' answer up there is good. Yet, there is no need for `date: now` as rgchris has done:

```
rejoin [
    now/year 
    pad/left/with now/month 2 #"0" 
    pad/left/with now/day 2 #"0" 
    "_" 
    pad/left/with first (now/time) 2 #"0" 
    pad/left/with second (now/time) 2 #"0" 
]
```

Comment: There is very definitely a need for the `date: now`. If your multiple NOW calls straddle a midnight boundary you will get incorrect results at best.